# Use CSP nonce without server side rendering (cookie)

Tags: javascript, cookies, content-security-policy, nonce

When building a web app with separated frontend and backend (no server side rendering) [I still want to make use of CSP nonce](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/troubleshoot/support/#content-security-policy-rules). Usually the CSP header and the html should contain the same nonce, which is no problem with SSR but seems to be impossible without SSR.

Now I thought of a different way to make use of the nonce without SSR:

- Server: Besides sending the nonce with the CSP header, also send it as a cookie (still changing for every request!) [This also seems to be a common approach for CSRF](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf#user-content-single-page-application-spa)
- UI: instead of including the `<script>` which needs a nonce directly inside the html, rather load it dynamically from my own script:

```js
const script = document.createElement('script')
script.setAttribute('src', 'https://example.com')
script.setAttribute('data-csp-nonce', getCspNonceFromCookie())
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Is this a valid approach for this problem? Are there security concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution works. One of my projects does it in a similar way. But you should set a `nonce` attribute instead of `data-csp-nonce`.

```
script.setAttribute('nonce', 'THE-GENERATED-NONCE')
```

So the script tag looks like:

```
<script nonce="jETnT70lr0T3Hw4b5WeCjuJ421a3kcBl">
    // ...
</script>
```

This is only secure when the headers, send by the server, includes already `content-security-policy` which denies external scripts. E.g.:

```
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-jETnT70lr0T3Hw4b5WeCjuJ421a3kcBl'; img-src 'self' data:; object-src 'none'
```

Comment: Isn’t generating the nonce “server side rendering”? You *are* sending a different randomly generated nonce on each load, right?

Comment: That's right. On every request a new nonce should be generated.

Comment: I’m surprised that works. I didn’t think you could send CSP nonces after render

Comment: It is stored in a cookie (or as meta tag). So your own script can get the nonce from there and inject a nonced `<script nonce="...">` tag.

Comment: My very question is: Could an attacker use that same cookie to inject his own script the same way you do?